# unable to send mail though log4net config

Tags: c#, email, configuration, log4net

It is not sending mail when there is a error logged in my log file.
Can anyone see what is the problem because I can see an error logged in the log file?

THnx

Comment: Could you post the error and the code which sends the email?

Comment: <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    <threshold value="WARN"/>
    <to value="xyz@gmail.com" />
    <from value="xyz@gmail.com" />
    <subject value="DTC" />
    <smtpHost value="smtphost" />
    <bufferSize value="512" />
    
    
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="entry:%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception:entry%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

Comment: Actually i was tryin from my machine tht is why it was not workin. I went to the server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on [internal debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121975/log4net-appenders-not-working-in-iis7-5/3126675#3126675)... is it logging to other appenders? Did you call the "XmlConfigurator.Configure" method (by code or attribute)?

Comment: Yes it is normally logging inside log4net.log file as I have a file appender.