# SQL Appender in log4net doesn't log dividebyzero errors

Tags: log4net

The errors are coming through fine in my file appender, but not in the sql appender.

Offending line:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1 / x;
```

EDIT: apparently it doesn't log anything that's unhandled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should post a little more information (e.g. the log4net configuration)... based on what you write I assume the following:

- You have an exception handler that calls log4net
- Exceptions logged thus are processed correctly by a file appender
- Logging of normal messages works fine for both appenders

I think that this means, there is something wrong with the configuration of the ado appender. Probably you try to pass the exception object and this somehow does not work correctly (type mismatch of sorts). Turning on [internal debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121975/log4net-appenders-not-working-in-iis7-5/3126675#3126675) should indicated exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: Turns out it was the buffersize. Setting it to one made it one to one report. Embarrassed....